# Java Mouse Event - MouseClicked works fine but MousePressed and MouseReleased don't

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I try to handle MousePressed event in class A, which extends from abstract class B and implements interface C, but I only handle MouseClicked, MousePressed does not work

interface C

```
    public interface C {

    public void setText(String msg, Dimension d);

    public void setVisible(boolean b);

    public boolean isVisible();

    public Dimension getSize();

    public void setLocation(Point p);

}
```

Abstract class B

```
public abstract class B {
public B() {
}

int x, y, w, h, size;

private boolean visible = false;

MouseListener mouseListener = null;

boolean isInner(int p_x, int p_y) {
    ......
}

public void addMouseListener(MouseListener l) {
    mouseListener = l;
}

public void setVisible(boolean b) {
    .....
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    ........
}

public void repaint() {
    .......
}

public void setSize(int size) {
    .......
}

public void setLocation(int x, int y) {
    ........
}

public Dimension getSize() {
    .......
}

public Point getLocationOnScreen() {
    .........
}
```

}

My Class A:

```
public class A extends B implements C {

private String _text;

private String[] _lines;

private Color _backgroundColor = new Color(255, 255, 192);

private Color _borderColor = new Color(128, 128, 128);

private Color _foreColor = Color.black;

private int _fontSize = 9;

private boolean inner_viewer = false;

private TextLayout textLayout;

private TextLayout _lstTextLayout[];


public A(String msg, Dimension d, int fontSize, Color foreColor, Color bkColor, Color borderColor) {

    setText(msg, d, fontSize, foreColor, bkColor, borderColor);

    inner_viewer = EXE_NAME.equals(D.get_extensionToolCommand());

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            System.err.println("Released");
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.err.println("Pressed");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            System.err.println("Exited");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.err.println("Entered");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.err.println("Click");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void setText(String msg, Dimension d, int fontSize, Color foreColor, Color bkColor, Color borderColor) {
    this._fontSize = fontSize;
    this._foreColor = foreColor;
    this._backgroundColor = bkColor;
    this._borderColor = borderColor;
    this._text = msg;
    this.w = d.width;
    this.h = d.height;
    this._lines = _text.split("\n");
    this._lstTextLayout = new TextLayout[_lines.length];
}

@Override
public void setLocation(Point p) {
    super.setLocation(p.x, p.y);
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    ................
}}
```

I don't understand "why only MouseClicked work fine, all of another event of mouse do not work".

thanks for all answer.

Comment: I am wondering how you managed to pass a `MouseListener` to a method requiring `MouseAdapter`. Does this even compile?

Comment: You have your custom `addMouseListener()` in `B`, however, that expects `MouseAdapter` rather than `MouseListener`, so the code would not compile. If it did, then the behaviour would be dependent on what `B` does with the listener, rather than how swing usually behaves.

Comment: I edited code class B, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: The question still remains: *what does B do with the listener?* The shown code only stores it to the field `l`, but if clicked event works, it must be doing something else with it too. And the behaviour of the other events depends on that something else. Another possibility is that you have *another* mouse listener somewhere that is using the normal `addMouseListener()`, and prints only the clicked event.

Comment: @kiheru yes, in class B, it was where stored listener, I try print to system console with all of mouse event, but only clicked event work fine, 
the others not work. 
I will review all code too, thanks your answer.

Comment: @kiheru I reviewed code, but nowhere have addMouseListener() too.

Comment: If `B` does not do anything else with the listener than store it, `mouseClicked()` will *never* be run. So either `B` does something with it, or you have some other code that prints "Click".

Comment: @kiheru I reviewed all of file, I think nowhere and no method handle mouseListener except class A, I don't understand how clicked event work fine, and others not work. (only class A implement B and C)

Comment: **Nothing** should work fine with the posted code. Either `B` uses `mouseListener` somewhere, or there's some other code that prints "Click". In other words, you haven't posted the code needed to solve the problem.

Comment: @kiheru thanks for your comment, I think problem was solved, in an another class define mouse event for A class, I saw in it only have mouseClicked event. Thank you again. I will post class define mouseEvent to answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are claiming is not possible. MouseClicked is the little brother of MousePressed and MouseReleased... It is not a system event by itself, but rather a synthetic one generated by the timing between MousePressed and MouseReleased. For further proof of this, check out java.awt.Robot... see the MouseClicked method in there? No, because there isn't one.

Not possible. Case closed

Comment: But, I have question, how to clicked event fire and both pressed and released don't. I release don't understand, what happen when I pressed or released mouse button. why them don't work but clicked(pressed then released mouse button in short time) work fine?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved, I found where define mouseEvent for A class, I added comment where I define new mouse event.

Class AScreen:

```
public class AScreen extends JWindow {

..................................

private MouseListener callIfNeed(A a) {
    if (a == null || a.mouseListener == null) {
        final MouseListener dummy = new MouseAdapter() {
        };
        return dummy;
    }
    return a.mouseListener;
}

private InnerAnnotateSticky frontA(MouseEvent e1) {
    Point p = e1.getPoint();
    for (int i = front_element.size() - 1; i >= front.size(); i--) {
        if (front_element.get(i).isInner(p.x, p.y))
            return (A) front_element.get(i);
    }
    return null;
}

private enum MOUSE_EVENT {
    CLICK,
    //define new mouse event
    PRESSED,
    RELEASED,
}

private MouseAdapter adapter = new MouseAdapter() {

    private void mouseEventUpdate(MOUSE_EVENT event, MouseEvent e) {

        synchronized (getInstance()) {
            if (event.equals(MOUSE_EVENT.CLICK)) {
                A a = frontA(e);
                MouseListener listener = callIfNeed(a);
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.mouseClicked(e);
                }
            }

            // add new mouse event 
            if (event.equals(MOUSE_EVENT.PRESSED)) {
                A a = frontA(e);
                MouseListener listener = callIfNeed(a);
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.mousePressed(e);
                }
            }

            if (event.equals(MOUSE_EVENT.RELEASED)) {
                A a = frontA(e);
                MouseListener listener = callIfNeed(a);
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.mouseReleased(e);
                }
            }

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseEventUpdate(MOUSE_EVENT.CLICK, e);
    }

    //I add new 2 override method
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseEventUpdate(MOUSE_EVENT.PRESSED, e);
    };

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseEventUpdate(MOUSE_EVENT.RELEASED, e);
    };
};
........................
```

}

Thanks for all answer!